# How to ignore specific JSON field when converting JSON string to Java object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json data as response from the Database, which I need to Map to my Java Pojo.

## Json response:

```
{
"Vehicle" { 
 "travelMedium" : "road",
"CarList" : {
    "car": [
       {
        "company": "Maruthi",
         "color" : "red"   
       },
       {
        "company": "Honda",
         "color" : "black"   
       },
       {
        "company": "Swift",
         "color" : "white"   
       }
      ] 
  }
 }
}
```

## Pojos

```
Class Vehicle {
  String travelMedium;
  List<Car> car;

}


Class Car {
  private company;
  private color;
}
```

I am using Jackson for this Deserialization which Will bind json to the Java object but the additional 
field CarList gives error. I want to avoid "CarList" field when it is binding (json string to Java Pojo).

I would like to know an approach to achieve this. Or any suggestions would be great.

Comment: what is the error you are getting for Carlist? also you are aware that `private company;
  private color` is not correct syntax you are missing data type

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its not that clean. But if you want to avoid having this `carList` field in your pojo, you can do something like this :

You can provide a setter method and set the field you actually need.

```
@JsonProperty("carList")
public void setCarList(Map<String, List<Car>> cars) {
  this.car = cars.get("carList");
}
```

Comment: Probably you have to read it as `Map<String, Object>` and then cast it. You can test.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't want to ignore the `CarList` field, you want to "unwrap" it automatically.

You will probably need a wrapper class for this:

```
public class CarList {
    private final List<Car> car;
    @JsonCreator
    public CarList(@JsonProperty("car") List<Car> car) {
        this.car = car == null ? Collections.emptyList() : Collection.unmodifiableList(car);       
    }
    ... 
}
```

Then

```
public class Vehicle {
    private final String travelMedium;
    private final List<Car> car;
    @JsonCreator
    public CarList(@JsonProperty("travelMedium") String travelMedium,
                   @JsonProperty("CarList") CarList carList) {
        this.travelMedium = travelMedium;
        this.car = carList == null ? Collections.emptyList() : Collection.unmodifiableList(carList.getCar());
    }
    ... 
}
```